# MySQL - prevent a row from referencing itself

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

I've got a table *categories* with the following structure:

```
----------------------------------
| id (PK) | name | parentId (FK) |
----------------------------------
```

where *parentId* can reference a row in the same table.

I want to prevent a row from being updated so that it references to itself (*parentId* != *id*). I know that I have to use a database trigger, but I have no idea how it should look. How can I do this please?

I know I could (and also will) handle this in the application logic, but I don't think it's a good practice handling these kind of things in the application logic only.

I also want to prevent cyclic references on insert and update, but I guess that is a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of Googling, thinking and reading tutorials, I've managed to create the trigger that I wanted myself:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER prevent_circular_reference
    BEFORE UPDATE ON category
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DECLARE x INT;
        SET x = NEW.parentId;
        WHILE x > 0 DO
            IF OLD.id = x THEN
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE "45000"
                    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "Cannot change parentId as it would create a circular reference.";
            END IF;
            SELECT parentId FROM category WHERE id = x INTO x;
        END WHILE;
    END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The trigger is fired before every update on the table. It checks that the category which should become the parent of the current category is not a child of the current category. If a circular reference (including a row referencing itself) would be created by updating, an error is raised by using the SIGNAL keyword.

Note that this asssumes that *id* is set to autoincrement starting with 1 (the default behavior), because if the SELECT returns NULL, a zero is inserted into *x*.

Comment: Did you find this to be slow? Was a foreign key constraint also used? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: The speed is OK. Moreover, I'll be limiting the nesting depth to 5 or 10 (not sure yet), so I doubt there would be any significant speed penalty. But I've been already Googling this and Oracle seems to be a lot faster: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/28/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-oracle/ And yes, FK constraint was used.

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to do with a check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE categories 
ADD CONSTRAINT categories_no_self_ref_ck CHECK (id != parentid)
```

Comment: From MySQL Docs, "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines"

Comment: The 5.7 manual says: "The CHECK value is not available until we support CHECK." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-constraints-table.html

Comment: As the others have already pointed out, this does not work with MySQL. The constraint is being simply ignored. That's why I said earlier I needed a trigger.